# Is it alright to enforce users to update an ios application on their devices?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I was just wondering what are the guidlines and policies about updating an app on app store? Are we allowed to enforce the users to upgrade their applications programatically?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's review policies and not a programming question.

Comment: Having said that, I've seen several apps in the store that force you to update.

Comment: this is very important for a programmer like myself to know wether he/she is allowed to force the users to upgrade their apps. And off course this is a programming related questions.

Comment: Read the description from the [tag:appstore-approval] tag. A question like this is better asked on the Apple developer forums.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to give you some key-points, that might be useful in yours app-update strategies.

1. **Non forced update**: (1.X.X) You can use this strategy when you updated your app slightly and updating to it will provide user more delight product. Then you might use simple UIAlertView with notification about new version update and it's features and OK|Cancel buttons, that lead to appStore. This notification can be shown, for example, every time user launches the app. Every `applicationDidBecomeActive` call can ask your server for actual information about new version
2. **Forced update** (2.x.x) you might find it useful, when you made breaking changes on your server-side or you decided to stop supporting some old versions of the app. Then after server-call and retrieving information about app deprecation a modal viewcontroller can be shown with only button, that leads to AppStore and text, that informs about new version available.

Both of these scenarios are used in my apps, and I've never had any troubles with Apple's policies.